# optimize sql pagination

Tags: sql, sql-server

## How to optimize pagination query

### RowCount :179418043

```
select  * from Table WP
 ORDER BY WP.Id desc
      OFFSET 20 * (1 - 1) ROWS
      FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

To get 20 records from the DB it took more than 2 mins

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

Comment: You need appropriate indexing applied in the table considering search columns.

Comment: Considering that the OP is yusing `SELECT *` then it'll need to at least `INCLUDE` every column in the table.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Answer (score 0):

Create an inner and outer query. In your inner query match only the ID's instead of all *, and crucially also make sure your sort/match attribute has an index on it. This operation should be O(logN) which is the time for finding an element in an ordered set, and you won't have to order the set plus search  ( O(n*LogN) + O(logN) ---> O(nLogN) ) since it is already sorted (the price you pay is a bit extra time @ insertion time).  After your first select of Id's, make a 2nd Query for getting the data of only those rows matching those 20 Id's.